# Hoarseness after 5-6 songs of singing

Tags: voice, practice

I started 6 months ago to sing and at the beginning i was feeling very bad in every song. I mean it seemed that i was damaging my voice in every song. Now i'm better at this, when i reach those 5-7 songs i start to feel something weird on my throat, some breathy voice on lower volume speach, some little scratch or little burn but that freak me off and i stop myself immediately. That strange feel disappear in like 1 hour maximum. Is this normal at the beginning? Is like that has to do with the control of air, of breathy voice? is something that better with time? I have a breathy voice not for choice, and that's beacuse i still cant control that so nice but that doesnt give me any tickle while i'm singing.Tthose feeling/symptoms appears just after 5-6 songs without any signal. Maybe has to do with the vocal range too: i'm a bass/baritone i can hit E2 and F4 in chest voice (or even more but i feel like i'm straining if i try to go higher and i start to lost many harmonics) and when i hit those notes from D2 i feel like i can't just sing all songs in those notes, and maybe that's one of the causes. give me some tips please singing a maximum of 6 songs is so annoying and i dont want to hurt my vocal chords. Ah yes i always, and repeat ALWAYS do warm up, cooldown, breath exercise and intervals exercises.

Comment: If you do **only** warmups, do you ever get that same hoarse feeling?

Comment: Mmm sometimes but just when i go in falsetto for the vocalizes and not everytime. But maybe i don't consider warming up as you. For me warming up is doing some exercises for become awarness of mask projection, or for trying to eliminate breathy sound, or just for pratice the vowels in a way that is relaxed, so the primary reason i do this exercises is for learning not for warming up my voice. I already tried 2-3 times to not do any warm up and i get those strange feelings in 8-9 songs so it seems just the same